# correct way of using IgniteDataStreamer API

Tags: ignite

I have a multi threaded application which keeps writing to ignite cache using write() method. At startup, it calls init() method which creates a cache and streamer object. Once all threads are done, flush() is called which close the streamer and write any keys which failed to insert in write() method. I have some queries.

1. In a write() method, what should i do with IgniteFuture? Should i wait on it until it is completed?
2. Is this future get complete when entry is written into cache or into streamer internal buffer?
3. In a flush() method, I am writing all the entries which failed in a write() method before closing streamer object. Is this a correct way?
   code below:

   ```
   public void initialize(final String cacheName) {
     getOrCreateCache(cacheName, true); // create new cache or get existing if it already exists
     this.streamer = ignite.dataStreamer(cacheName);
     this.cacheName = cacheName;
   }

   public void write(K key, V value) {
   try {
     IgniteFuture<?> future = streamer.addData(key, value); // what to do with this future. Should i wait on that?
     numberOfEntriesWrittentIntoCache.incrementAndGet();
    } catch (IgniteInterruptedException | IgniteDataStreamerTimeoutException | CacheException | IllegalStateException e) {
      failedMap.put(key, value);
    }
   }

   public void flush() {
   try {
     if (streamer != null) {
       if (failedMap.size() > 0) {
         LOGGER.info("Writing " + failedMap.size() + " failed entries");
         failedMap.forEach((k, v) -> writeToGrid(k, v));
       }
     }
   } catch (IllegalStateException | CacheException | IgniteException e) {
     LOGGER.error("Exception while writing/closing ignite");
   } catch (Exception e) {
     LOGGER.error("Exception while writing/closing ignite");
   } finally {
     failedMap.clear();
     if (streamer != null) {
       streamer.close();
       streamer = null;
     }
     LOGGER.info("Number of entries written into cache are " + numberOfEntriesWrittentIntoCache.intValue());
   }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data streamer sends data to other nodes in batches. Future, returned from `addData` method is completed, when a batch with the provided entry is flushed into a cache.

So, if you wait for completion of each future, returned from `addData(...)` method, then you may never wait till it's completed, if [autoFlushFrequency](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteDataStreamer.html#autoFlushFrequency-long-) is not configured and `flush()` or `close()` is not called. And even if `autoFlushFrequency` is configured, then each call to `write()` method will wait till the batch is flushed.

I don't see anything bad in trying to write failed entries to data streamer again at the end of all processing. But I don't really know a case, when it may be useful.

The only thing, that I would change is wrapping `writeToGrid(k, v)` inside the `forEach` into its own try-catch block. Otherwise one exception will stop processing of all failed entries.